Error: No version of module @jupyter-widgets/base is registered
I am trying to connect power bi reports which are hosted on power bi service. Below is the code for the same. Device flow authentication successfully completed, but it is giving me below error
from powerbiclient import Report, models
import requests

tenant_id = 'AAA'
client_id = 'BBB'
client_secret = 'CCC'  # Be cautious with secrets!

url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

body = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope': 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the access token from the response
    access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
    #print("Access Token acquired successfully!")
    #print(access_token)  # For debugging purposes only, don't print secrets in production
else:
    # Print the error details if the token request failed
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Error response: {response.json()}")


group_id="DDD"
report_id="EEE"

report = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, auth=access_token)
report

Versions:
powerbiclient : 3.1.1
ipywidgets : 8.1.3
jupyter-ui-poll: 1.0.0
msal : 1.30.0
pandas: 2.2.2
pyspark : 3.5.2
request : 2.32.2

Getting below error:
[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Failed to load view class 'ErrorWidgetView' from module '@jupyter-widgets/base'
Error: No version of module @jupyter-widgets/base is registered

I'm confused. Are you trying to port this over from a special place it runs to vanilla Jupyter? A lot of times you see things like this when you haven't refreshed after installing ipywidgets. Did you shut down the browser and Jupyter and restart since ipywidgets was installed? More importantly, perhaps, did you do a hard reload on your browser and try running things after that? On Chrome on a Mac it is Command+shift+r to reload. I think it is Shift-F5 on Windows.

instead of access tokens if i use DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication it is working fine, is my above code is wrong. Please suggest. I want to automate this process so can't go with  DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication. Can you suggest any other best approach for automation.

I am unable to comment on your code because you post title and text don't include enough detail for me to help. I would suggest editing to make your title better then so people familiar with where you are working see it.  Or perhaps post a new post.  Power-bi people may be able to understand better? Your most recent comments seem to be another issue and so it should probably a different post taking some of these suggestions into account. And if you want to automate, I'm not sure you are doing this correctly if it involves widgets as they are interactive.
